# Unix: using the fork, exec and wait system call for command interpreter

Tags: unix, exec

I was able to refine the program further, but still need a little help in terms of storing the now separate words into an array. My current code only takes in the first word/command only. Here's my new code:

```
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include<sys/types.h>
    #include<sys/wait.h>
    #include<cstdio>
    #include<cstdlib>
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;

int main(){
    int pid,status,rs;
    char comm[100];
    cout<<"Enter command:\n ";
    cin.getline(comm,100);
    char *token=strtok(comm," ");
    pid=fork();
    if(pid==-1)
    {
        perror("fork");
        exit(pid);
    }
    if(pid==0)
    {
        while(token!=NULL){
        char *argv[]={token,0};
        
        
        
        rs=execvp(argv[0],argv);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
        if(rs==-1)
        {
            perror("execvp");
            exit(rs);
        }
        
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Done waiting for: "<<wait(&status)<<endl;
    }
}
```

The outcome of the code should be something like this:

```
% ./z123456
Enter command: mkdir one
Enter command: touch one/file one/other one/more
Enter command: ls -l one
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 student student 0 Apr  3 13:03 file
-rw-r--r-- 1 student student 0 Apr  3 13:03 more
-rw-r--r-- 1 student student 0 Apr  3 13:03 other
Enter command: gobly gook
gobly: No such file or directory
Enter command: cd one
cd: No such file or directory
Enter command: exit
%
```

Comment: You have to parse the input in `comm` and split it into arguments. As you don't know how many arguments the user will enter, use a vector based `exec*` variant instead of the list based `execl`. You probably want to search the command in `PATH`,so  I suggest to use `execvp`. The first argument of all `exec*` functions is the program to execute, i.e. the first word the user has entered, not a constant string. For the final version call `wait` without printing the output. For error message like `gobly: No such file or directory` to pass the first word (`gobly`) to `perror()` instead of `"execl"`

Comment: So I should replace: rs=execl("home/student/Assignment8",comm,(char*)NULL) with the following here: rs=execvp(comm,"home/student/Assignment8") is that right so far?

Comment: No. Read the documentation of `execvp`. If `comm` contains the command line `touch one/file one/other one/more` you have to split this into words and store pointers to the words in an array (`argv`). `argv[0]` should point to `"touch"`, `argv[1]` to `"one/file"`, `argv[2]` to `"one/more"` and `argv[3]` must be `NULL`. Then call `rs=execvp(argv[0], argv)`. **Use your favorite search engine to find example code.** With the search keywords "execvp example" I found several examples of different quality. One of them is this: http://www.cs.ecu.edu/karl/4630/sum01/example1.html